# Navbar com problemas

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, nav-bar

Estou fazendo um projeto, e quando reduzo a tela, a navbar muda para o padrão mobile, fazendo ela ser responsiva, ai quando clico nos 3 tracinhos do menu navbar, ele baixa o conteúdo e exibe normalmente, porém quando clico novamente, ele não volta...  ficando assim como na imagem, ou seja, ela não volta ao normal como deveria. onde pode estar o erro?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        @{
            Projeto.Models.Pessoa pessoa = Projeto.Repositorios.Funcoes.GetUsuario();
            string nome;
            int acesso = 0;
            int id = 0;
            if (pessoa == null)
            {
                <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" type="button">
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Projeto", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                            </div>
                            <center>
                                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                                    <form action="~/Publico/Logar" method="post" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required="required" autocomplete="on" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="password" id="senha" class="form-control" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" required="required" autocomplete="off" />
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-default" />
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            else
            {
                id = pessoa.PessoaID;
                nome = pessoa.Nome;
                if (pessoa.Tipo == 2)
                {
                    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Projeto", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Lista", "Index", "pessoa")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Cadastrar", "Create", "pessoa")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edit/" + @id, "pessoa")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sair", "Logoff", "Publico")</li>
                                </ul>
                                <p class="navbar-right navbar-brand" style="font-size:medium">Bem-vindo @nome</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }

            }
            <div class="container body-content">
                @RenderBody()
                <footer class="footers">
                    <p class="footers" style="color:black">&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Tribus - Oruam</p>
                </footer>
            </div>
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/inputmask")
            @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
        }


        <script>
            (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
                i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
                }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
            })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-85534546-1', 'none');
            ga('send', 'pageview');

        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<style>
    .footers {
        width: 90%;
        bottom: 0;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
    }

    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .geral {
        min-height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        width: 800px;
    }



    #box {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-position: center;
    }

    #fixedbutton {
        bottom: 0;
        position: relative;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Coloque o código pro pessoal poder te ajudar melhor, o erro pode ser muitas coisas diferentes!

Comment: então eu acho que pode ser com algum script, pois já abri um novo projeto e copiei a navbar deste outro projeto que está funcionando para este projeto que não está, e não resolveu... e sobre o código, ele é grande de mais para por no comentário...

Comment: Coloca só as partes relacionadas com o navbar, porque assim não tem como te dar uma resposta precisa, saca?

Comment: Você tem esse site em produção pra poder passar o link?

Comment: eu editei o post... o site não tenho, é um projeto de Faculdade, está em desenvolvimento ainda, está bem cru rs

Comment: o estranho é que se eu copiar este código e por no projeto qualquer aqui, ela funciona, só neste mesmo... vc saberia dizer qual script é responsável por ela?

Comment: Pode ser um script que esteja impedindo o funcionamento sim, faz um teste, tenta comentar todos os outros scripts que seu menu não precisa e testa pra ver se vai funcionar, se funcionar você vai descomentando um por um e testando, pra ver qual que tá dando problema.

Comment: os scripts necessários para funcionar é estes dois, se comentar os dois, ou um deles já não funciona... 
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

Comment: Então, como eu disse comenta todos os outros, menos esses!

Comment: sim, comentei todos e fui fazendo o processo... descomentando um por um e testando, pra ver qual funcionava, eu testava um, comentava novamente, e descomentava outro pra testar... assim até fazer com todos, porém vi que os únicos dois que precisam estar na página seriam estes dois, pois sem um deles não funcionava... os outros já estão comentados....

Comment: E só com esses dois habilitados o menu continua com o mesmo erro?

Comment: isso, pra funcionar precisa dos dois, e somente os dois habilitados o erro persiste...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta utilizar este código, caso esteja com a biblioteca jQuery, caso não esteja, é só colar este código no `<head>`:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    $(document).on( 'click', '#seuMenu', function() {
         $('.container-menu').slideToggle('slide');
    });
</head>
```

E este código abaixo você usa para o menu funcionar corretamente. Não esqueça de trocar os seletores.

```
$(document).on( 'click', '#seuMenu', function() {
    $('.container-menu').slideToggle('slide');
});
```

Comment: Desculpas cara, poderia me explicar melhor como uso este código?
Seria assim no Head:
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
        $(document).on('click', '#seuMenu', function () {
            $('.container-menu').slideToggle('slide');
        });
    </script>
</head>

Comment: Eu atualizei a resposta, agora basta trocar os seletores que são "#seuMenu" e ".container-menu" para os que você está utilizando =)